# C++ function call routes resolver

Tags: c++, windows, code-analysis

I'm looking for a tool that will tell/resolve for every function all the call paths (call it "routes") to it.

For example:

```
void deeper(int *pNumber)
{
 *pNumber++;
}
void gateA(int *pNumber)
{
 deeper(pNumber);
}
void gateB(int *pNumber)
{
 gateA(pNumber);
}

void main()
{
 int x = 123;
 gateA(&x);
 gateB(&x);
}
```

See?
I need a tool that will tell me all the routes to deeper(), and more if possible.

By saying "more" I mean that it will tell me if the pointer is the same as been provided to the calling function.

This will greatly save me time.
Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to run on a specific platform (Windows, Mac OSX, Linux, OpenBSD, openSolaris, whatever)?

Comment: Does it have to detect indirect calls, such as through function pointers or virtual calls?

Comment: @David: I'm using Windows. For me that's enough.

@Rob: I wouldn't expect such a feature although this would greatly improve popularity, of the tool (:

It seems that people here has suggested good solutions. Will check it later.

Comment: I wasn't asking if you needed cross-platform, but what platform you needed it on.  Not all tools are available on all platforms.  I'm editing the tags to include "windows".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) will do that for you.  It'll draw you nice inheritance trees and show you everyone who is calling (and called by) your functions.

Comment: Was going to suggest that myself.

Answer (score 6):

I think [cppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/) has that functionality (along with other code analysis features)

Answer (score 1):

you can look at the [clang analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org).

> The Clang Static Analyzer is source code analysis tool that find bugs in C/C++ and Objective-C programs.

I didn't tried it but looking at the screenshots of code review, it might be usefull